# Including Lightning Message Service in Managed Package?

Tags: managed-package, lightning-message-service

I am attempting to make use of the Lightning Message Service to pass events between components when various actions occur (e.g. Sending an email, or authenticating the app.

The Salesforce docs suggest that the proper import syntax is

```js
// Syntax for resources in a managed package
import channelName from '@salesforce/messageChannel/namespace__channelReference';
```

So attempting to emulate that, my import reference is

```js
import DSMessageChannel from "@salesforce/messageChannel/DS_Packages__DSMessageChannel";
```

The app's namespace is **DS_Packages**, and the Message Channel file name is **DS_Packages__DSMessageChannel.messageChannel-meta.xml**. However, this is resulting in a Salesforce error:

> Invalid module id "DS_Packages__DSMessageChannel" for type "messageChannel". Explicit use of namespace "DS_Packages" in file "touchpoint.js" is prohibited. Use default namespace "c" instead.

Does anyone know how to resolve this naming issue, or has successfully used Lightning Message Service in a managed package? Below is the XML code for the Message channel, thank you to all in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <description>This is the DialSource Cadences Message Channel.</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <lightningMessageFields>
        <description>This is sample message</description>
        <fieldName>message</fieldName>
    </lightningMessageFields>
    <masterLabel>DSMessageChannel</masterLabel>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

Comment: I wonder if the issue is the inclusion of the namespace prefix on the metadata file name; you don't normally have the namespace on files representing metadata in a managed package.